# How to send a value to the last defaulted parameter in a Groovy function?

Tags: groovy

I have a function like this:

```
def myFunctionName(one = 'one', two = 'two', three = 'three') {
```

I can't change the order of any parameter nor its default signature (since there are other services using it).

I want to call it replacing the third value only, but leaving the others as default, something like `myFunctionName(three: 'anotherValue')`.

What are the possibilities that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Groovy has no named parameters like other languages have (e.g. Kotlin).  The syntax you see like `myFunc(three: 'val')` is passing a `Map` and is short-hand for `myFunc([three: 'val'])` (using a map literal).

Since you can't change the base method, you are best off to extract the (assumingly) complex params for `one` and `two` and write your own function, that allows just passing `three`. And before you just add more permutations consider changing the passed in params to some configuration object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use right currying for that particular case:

```
def myFunction(one = 'one', two = 'two', three = 'three'){}

def myFunc1and2 = myFunction.rcurry( 'someValue' )

myFunc1and2( '1', '2' )
```